# LOAD_FILE in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access database that embeds images into fields within a table. This is outside of my control, as it's a third-party product that requires images be stored that way.

In the past (just because I had the knowledge and tools on hand), I've used an Access -> MySQL -> Access  ODBC driver to export the data to a MySQL, use `UPDATE` statements with the `LOAD_FILE` function to embed the photo, then export back to Access, where the third party program happily sees the images.

Today I decided to simplify the process by writing a VBA Macro that accepts a text file of filenames and executes the SQL necessary to load the files into the database.

The problem is, Access doesn't seem to have a notion of LOAD_FILE, because running this SQL:

```
UPDATE myTable SET PhotoField=LOAD_FILE('C:\\MyFiles\\SMITJOH.jpg') WHERE TextField3='SMITJOH';
```

Informs me that LOAD_FILE is an undefined function.

I'm using `DoCmd.RunSQL` to execute the line of SQL seen above. Is there a Microsoft equivalent of LOAD_FILE that I should look at?

Comment: What datatype is the column in Access?

Comment: @AlexK: An OLE Field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328395/how-to-create-an-ole-object-from-a-file-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

Effectively SQL haven't any function LOAD_FILE, probably is an external function of other control or similar.
So you can do this directly with stream image on Binary Field (BLOB).
Check the sample code that Microsoft include into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for VB.Net or C# (according to comments)

```
    Public Shared Function GetPhoto(filePath As String) As Byte()
      Dim stream As FileStream = new FileStream( _
      filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
      Dim reader As BinaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream)
      Dim photo() As Byte = reader.ReadBytes(stream.Length)
      reader.Close()
      stream.Close()
      Return photo
    End Function
```

As you can read this function read Binary Image to load to memory and then stream into any BinaryField.

For VBa this is another option to read or write into a field BLOB

```
Public Function FileToBlob(strFile As String, ByRef Field As Object)
On Error GoTo FileToBlobError

If Len(Dir(strFile)) > 0 Then
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim byteData() As Byte

    nFileNum = FreeFile()
    Open strFile For Binary Access Read As nFileNum
    If LOF(nFileNum) > 0 Then
        ReDim byteData(1 To LOF(nFileNum))
        Get #nFileNum, , byteData
        Field = byteData
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Error: File not found", vbCritical, _
           "Error reading file in FileToBlob"
End If

FileToBlobExit:
   If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
   Exit Function

FileToBlobError:
   MsgBox "Error " & err.Number & ": " & err.Description, vbCritical, _
       "Error reading file in FileToBlob"
   Resume FileToBlobExit
End Function


Public Function BlobToFile(strFile As String, ByRef Field As Object) As Long
On Error GoTo BlobToFileError

Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim abytData() As Byte
BlobToFile = 0
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open strFile For Binary Access Write As nFileNum
abytData = Field
Put #nFileNum, , abytData
BlobToFile = LOF(nFileNum)

BlobToFileExit:
   If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
   Exit Function

BlobToFileError:
   MsgBox "Error " & err.Number & ": " & err.Description, vbCritical, _
       "Error writing file in BlobToFile"
   BlobToFile = 0
   Resume BlobToFileExit

End Function
```

Comment: It seems that LOAD_FILE is a MySQL function and not part of many (if any?) other SQL variants. I'll give that code a shot and report back my findings. Thanks!

Comment: This is VB.Net, not VBA