# How to Insert Image to Access Database OLEobject Field

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vb.net-2010

I am trying to insert an image into OLEobject field by executing the following blocks of code.

```
    Private Sub BtnRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRegister.Click
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO `Std_Registeration` (`CNIC`, `Std_Name`, `Father_Name`, `Reg_number`, `Gender`, `Department`, `Semester`,`Std_Picture`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ('" & CNICTextBox.Text & "','" & Std_NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Father_NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Reg_numberTextBox.Text & "','" & GenderComboBox.Text & "','" & DepartmentTextBox.Text & "','" & SemesterTextBox.Text & "','" & Std_PicturePictureBox.ImageLocation & "','" & EmailTextBox.Text & "','" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "')", con)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Registeration Successful!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("OOPS! Something went wrong. Try Again!")
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

I know sending ImageLocation to OLEobject doesn't make any sense. It needs to be converted into Binary or something like that. I want to insert image into database field (OlEobject) properly.

Comment: -1. 478'000hits in 0.48sec on Google with access insert ole image. It is less work to look it up there. PLUS: there are 91 hits on SO for access OLE. One even with the title: Saving Image (byte[] BMP) to an Ole Photo Column

Comment: Please give me the code for conversion of image to OLEobject. Thanks

Comment: I think there is no one here to answer this query. Quite Strange !

Comment: Not strange. I showed you the way to do it: Google is your friend. It takes some time for everyone here to research and write a useful answer. This is not a free support service for the lazy. If you have problems with what you find online: edit your Question and include what problems you have and you will find plenty people to help you.

Comment: Access' OLE Object is a multi-valued field (i.e., several records in column) and cannot be updated or inserted with SQL into the backend Jet/ACE engine. You need to use the Access frontend GUI to import attachment or VBA's [OLE Embed handle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/158941) or [ADO Stream object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(v=vs.85).aspx). For latter, see this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328395/how-to-create-an-ole-object-from-a-file-ms-access).

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks