# What is the correct type for inserting OLE object?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data from a MS Access form in to a table so I've knocked up a short function to see whether it is possible.

The function I have is this:

```
Function Module2() As Boolean

On Error GoTo Err_Insert

  Dim adoCMD As Object
  Dim adoRS As Object
  Dim strSQL As String

  'Define a query to INSERT a new record into the FE temp table
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Table1] ([A1],[A2],[A3],[img] VALUES (p1,p2,p3,img);"

  'Define attachment to database table specifics
  Set adoCMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  With adoCMD
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(Forms("Form1").Controls("text0").value), Forms("Form1").Controls("Text0").value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p2", adBoolean, adParamInput, Len(Forms("Form1").Controls("Check2").value), Forms("Form1").Controls("Check2").value)
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p3", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(Forms("Form1").Controls("Combo4").value), Forms("Form1").Controls("Combo4").value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("img", adLongVarBinary, adParamInput, Len(Forms("Form1").OLEBound6), Forms("Form1").Controls("OLEBound6"))
    .CommandText = strSQL
    Set adoRS = .Execute
  End With

  'Return a good return code
  Module2 = True

Exit_Insert:
  'Clean up the connection to the database
  Set adoRS = Nothing
  Set adoCMD = Nothing

  Exit Function

Err_Insert:
  Call MsgBox("Class: Module2, Function: Insert()")
  Module2 = False
  Resume Exit_Insert

End Function
```

when run, I get the following error:

`Run-time error 3421
Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation`

and breaks at this point:

`.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("img", adLongVarBinary, adParamInput, Len(Forms("Form1").OLEBound6), Forms("Form1").Controls("OLEBound6"))`

What is the correct type for an OLEObject?  I've tried several all with the same result.  I cannot find which DataTypeEnum looks to be the correct type.

Thanks

Comment: I'd just do the insert using a recordset. See [this page](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20129881/How-do-I-insert-an-OLE-object-into-a-database-using-ADO.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create an ole object from a file - Ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328395/how-to-create-an-ole-object-from-a-file-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

When you skip parameter P3, the query will try to insert *img* (now the third parameter) to A3, thus the error.